# JS Class instance communication

Tags: javascript, class

I'm new with js classes and I think I'm not doing it right.

I want to achieve a simple thing here. On one card click I want to hide all other cards. But how can I reach other cards if event is triggered from inside of one of the cards?

```js
class Cards {
  constructor(args){
    this.list = [];
    this.amm = args.amm;
    this.createCards();
  }
  
  createCards(){
    for(var i=0; i<this.amm; i++){
      this.list.push( new Card( {id: i} ) );
    }
  }
}

class Card {
  constructor(args){
    this.id = args.id;
    this.el = null;
    this.createCard();
    this.addEvents();
  }
  
  createCard(){
    this.el = document.createElement("div");
    this.el.style.width = "60px";
    this.el.style.height = "100px";
    this.el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    this.el.style.margin = "5px";
    this.el.style.float = "left";
    document.body.appendChild(this.el);
  }
  
  addEvents(){
    let _this = this;
    this.el.onclick = function(){
      _this.el.style.opacity = 0.7;
      _this.hideOtherCards(_this.id);
    };
  }
  
  hideOtherCards(id){
    // how to hide other cards?
  }
}

var myCards = new Cards({amm: 5});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good practice (*encapsulation*) to keep the scope of any component limited to itself. That is, a card shouldn't know *that*, or *how many*, other cards exist. To keep the cards ***decoupled***, a common way to achieve that is to make use of **custom events**.

Imagine it like this: A card that is clicked shouts into the room "I was clicked" and relies upon someone hearing that and reacting to that and for that instance to know what to do. If noone reacts, your code still won't throw an error.

For this to work in your scenario, you'd need a host element for the cards as events bubble up the DOM, but don't bubble to siblings.

Long story short, this is what I'd do:

Edit: Actually, the `myCards` class should be responsible for creating the host element, and listening to `card-clicked`.

```js
class Cards {
  constructor(args){
    this.list = [];
    this.el = null;
    this.amm = args.amm;
    this.createCardHost();
  }
  
  createCardHost() {
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.createCards();
    this.el.addEventListener('card-clicked', (e) => {
      this.list.forEach(card => {card.id === e.detail.id ? card.el.style.opacity = 0.7 : card.el.style.opacity = 0.1})
    })
    for (const card of this.list) {
      this.el.appendChild(card.el)
    }
    document.body.appendChild(this.el);
  }
  
  createCards(){
    for(var i=0; i<this.amm; i++){
      this.list.push( new Card( {id: i} ) );
    }
  }
}

class Card {
  constructor(args){
    this.id = args.id;
    this.el = null;
    this.createCard();
    this.addEvents();
  }
  
  createCard(){
    this.el = document.createElement("div");
    this.el.style.width = "60px";
    this.el.style.height = "100px";
    this.el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    this.el.style.margin = "5px";
    this.el.style.float = "left";
  }
  
  addEvents(){
    this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.el.style.opacity = 0.7;
      //  throw a 'card-clicked' event here
      const cardClicked = new CustomEvent('card-clicked', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, detail: { id: this.id }});
      this.el.dispatchEvent(cardClicked);
    });
  }
}

var myCards = new Cards({amm: 5});
```

Comment: This is nice. Thank You!